# Office365-REST-Python-Client 401 on File Update

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I finally got over the hurdle of uploading files into SharePoint which enabled me to answer my own question here:
[Office365-REST-Python-Client Access Token issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236329/office365-rest-python-client-access-token-issue/57251976#57251976)

However, the whole point of my project was to add metadata to the files being uploaded to make it possible to filter on them. For the avoidance of double, I am talking about column information in Sharepoints Document Libraries.

Ideally, I would like to do this when I upload the files in the first place but my understanding of the rest API is that you have to upload first and then use a PUT request to update its metadata.

The link to the Git Hub for Office365-REST-Python-Client:
https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

This Libary seems to be the answer but the closest I can find to documentation is under the examples folder. Sadly the example for update file metadata does not exist. I think part of the reason for this stems from the only option being to use a PUT request on a list item.

According to the REST API documentation, which this library is built on, an item's metadata must be operated on as part of a list.

REST API Documentation for file upload:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest

REST API Documentation for updating list metadata:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#update-list-item

There is an example for updating a list item:
'https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/listitems_operations_alt.py' but it returns a 401. If you look at my answer to my own question in the link-up top you will see that I granted this App full control. So an unauthorized response and stopped has stopped me dead in my tracks wondering what to do next.

So after all that, my question is:
How do I upload a file to a Sharepoint Document Libary and add Metadata to its column information using Office365-REST-Python-Client?

Kind Regards
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Upload` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest) request

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')/Files/Add(url='file name', overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: contents of binary file
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

could be converted to the following Python example:

```
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)

file_info = FileCreationInformation()
file_info.content = file_content
file_info.url = os.path.basename(path)
file_info.overwrite = True
target_file = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url("Shared Documents").files.add(file_info)
ctx.execute_query()
```

Once file is uploaded, it's metadata could be set like this:

```
list_item = target_file.listitem_allfields # get associated list item 
list_item.set_property("Title", "New title")
list_item.update()
ctx.execute_query()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I stumbled upon this post and Office365-REST-Python-Client in general. However, I'm currently stuck trying to update a file's metadata, I keep receiving:

```
'File' object has no attribute 'listitem_allfields'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Note, I also updated this module to v 2.3.1

Here's my code:

```
list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(filename, filecontents)    
ctx.execute_query()
list_item = target_file.listitem_allfields
```

I've also tried:

```
library_root = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url('Shared Documents')
file_info = FileCreationInformation()
file_info.overwrite = True
file_info.content = filecontent
file_info.url = filename
upload_file = library_root.files.add(file_info)
ctx.load(upload_file)
ctx.execute_query()
list_item = upload_file.listitem_allfields
```

I've also tried to get the uploaded file item directly with the same result:

```
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(filename, filecontent)    
ctx.execute_query()

uploaded_file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(target_file.serverRelativeUrl)
print(uploaded_file.__dict__)
list_item = uploaded_file.listitem_allfields
```

All variations return:

```
'File' object has no attribute 'listitem_allfields'
```

What am I missing? How to add metadata to a new SPO file/list item uploaded via Python/Office365-REST-Python-Client

**Update:**
The problem was I was looking for the wrong property of the uploaded file. The correct attribute is:

```
uploaded_file.listItemAllFields
```

Note the correct casing. Hopefully my question/answer may help someone else who's is as ignorant as me of attribute/object casing.

Comment: had a similar issue, you might find the issue I raised/solved with Vgrem's help on Github interesting: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/244#issuecomment-674102807