# Office365 Rest API Python - add new rows of data to Lookup columns in sharepoint list

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

I’m trying to push new rows of data to a share point list. The list has a mix of different column types : text and Person/Group column types. I’m unable to find an example that shows how we can push new data to a lookup column, only updating it. (Link here: [Office365-REST-Python-Client seems unable to update Lookup Columns in Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68180216/office365-rest-python-client-seems-unable-to-update-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint))

Updating is troublesome for my use case. Would appreciate any insights on how I can push data directly to a lookup column. Thanks.